# How to prevent blank rows being created in Textfiles

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem regarding to the blank rows being created in my text file generated.How am i going to prevent this to happen?

Original text file Data with no blank rows created
`00|MAABBJQQ|AJ_20161206_001||||||||||||||||||||||||||`

Whenever i clicked my button( button is point to macro `sub test()` posted below) 5 times which contains the incremental function

```
00|MAABBJQQ|AJ_20161206_005||||||||||||||||||||||||||  
*blank row 1
*blank row 2
*blank row 3
*blank row 4
*blank row 5
```

Here are my incremental function codes for you guys to understand what i am going.

```
Sub test()
Dim fn As String, txt As String, myVal, temp
fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("TextFiles,*.txt")
If fn = "False" Then Exit Sub
txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "_(\d+)(?=\|)"
    myVal = Format$(.Execute(txt)(0).submatches(0) + 1, "_000")
    txt = .Replace(txt, myVal)
    Open Replace(fn, ".txt", "_Increment.txt") For Output As #1
        Print #1, txt
        MsgBox "This is batch No" & myVal
    Close #1
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is batch number the `BBB` in this pattern: `XX_YYYYMMDD_BBB` ?

Comment: just BBB, the XX_YYYYMMDD is prefix which is generated from my report tools, i've done this test module to make the BBB increment only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a semicolon `;` at the end of your `Print` statement:

```
Print #1, txt;
```

Details on the `Print #` statement can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264278.aspx). Note the *charpos* argument setting. Using a semicolon there will suppress a newline (`CRLF`) from being inserted.

Comment: Oh my god, that's simple.